# What is the best practice for installing external Emacs package dependencies?

Tags: emacs

Althought Emacs is quite competent at downloading and installing specified package dependencies, sometimes some of these dependencies are outside the control of Emacs and hence must be installed directly by the user. Examples are linters, checkers and language environments.

For example elpy-mode for python may have external dependencies like rope, jedi, flake8 etc. Another one is a JavaScript mode that may have some node package dependencies.

The trouble I face sometimes is, by default, I use local environments for isolation purposes when developing therefore I do get checkers and linters not working because Emacs is expecting them to be installed globally while I have installed them locally. Of course I try to fix them but not always successfull.

Some package maintainers are kind enough to clearly tell you how any external dependencies need to be installed while others just tell you to install assuming one knows what to do.

I currently have `tern not found; flycheck checker complains` etc that I'm trying to figure out by trying to install them in various locations to see if Emacs will find them.

As a guide, I'll appreciate anybody who wouldn't mind giving me some general pointers on how to install external dependencies in Emacs especially for Javascript and Python development.

Comment: I *suspect* there's no general solution to this problem. You could certainly suggest to library authors that they offer suggestions on installing dependencies, but there are often as many different ways of doing that as there are platforms on which they might be installed, and in such cases the author of the (portable) elisp integration could be forgiven for not wishing to be responsible for figuring out and explaining all the possibilities.

Comment: I will also mention [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) as an interesting example of a library which endeavours to take care of dependencies for you. You enable the library by calling `(pdf-tools-install)` and that function will attempt to install all the dependencies if it can't find what it needs. Authors of other libraries might contemplate whether they could do likewise, and whether pdf-tools provides a useful template for them.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the comments. Indeed I appreciate it might be hard to give a general solution hence my mention of Javascript and Python development. Even for experienced developers (let alone new ones), I believe the last thing one needs is battling tooling and environment setup problems in additon to the usual language, algorithm, design, etc challenges. I know I've given up on learning a couple of languages becuase I just couldn't get an adequate support in my editor.